# Difference in behavior when building with --prod option

Tags: angular

I observe a difference in behavior when I build the below code with --Prod option (ng build --prod) and without (ng build).

The if else stack (with the instanceof check) does not get invoked when:

- the project is compiled with --prod option

and

- the console.log statement removed.

The code works properly if the console.log is retained and built with --prod option.

The code works properly with or without the console.log when running in dev mode. (ng serve)

**Service Method**

```
 getTrends(porfolioId:string):Observable<Trend[]>{
return this._portfolioService
    .getPortfolioRef(porfolioId)
    .collection(this.collection_trends,ref=>{
      return ref.orderBy('date','desc').limit(100);
    })
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(actions => {

        return actions.map(action => {

          let trend:Trend = new Trend();

          trend=action.payload.doc.data() as Trend;


          if(trend.date instanceof firestore.Timestamp){
            let ts:firestore.Timestamp=trend.date;
            trend.date=new Date(ts.toDate());
            console.log('trend.date (fs ts) converted to date'+trend.date);   
          }else{
            trend.date=new Date(trend.date);

          }

          return trend;
        })
      })
    );


}
```

**Compiled Code without Console.log**

```
e.prototype.getTrends = function(e) {
                    return this._portfolioService.getPortfolioRef(e).collection(this.collection_trends, function(e) {
                        return e.orderBy("date", "desc").limit(100)
                    }).snapshotChanges().pipe(Object(w.a)(function(e) {
                        return e.map(function(e) {
                            var t = new ne;
                            return t.date = (t = e.payload.doc.data()).date instanceof re.firestore.Timestamp ? new Date(t.date.toDate()) : new Date(t.date), t
                        })
                    }))
                }
```

**Compiled Code with Console.log**

```
return e.prototype.getTrends = function(e) {
                    return this._portfolioService.getPortfolioRef(e).collection(this.collection_trends, function(e) {
                        return e.orderBy("date", "desc").limit(100)
                    }).snapshotChanges().pipe(Object(w.a)(function(e) {
                        return e.map(function(e) {
                            var t = new ne;
                            return (t = e.payload.doc.data()).date instanceof re.firestore.Timestamp ? (t.date = new Date(t.date.toDate()), console.log("trend.date (fs ts) converted to date" + t.date)) : t.date = new Date(t.date), t
                        })
                    }))
                }
```

Angular version is 6.0.6

What could be the reason for the difference in behavior and how can i remove the console.log?

Comment: your `Compiled Code without Console.log` is correct and it contains your if-else code. What is the problem?

Comment: The code is there but it does not get executed. If the if else stack get executed I should get a date object in the date field. This does not happen. If i debug it in the browser developer tools and step thru the execution, I see that the control skips the if else stack.

Comment: @Vasco despite the slight difference in the structure of the return statement, the two are equivalent: in both the code with and without the log `t.date` is assigned `new Date(t.date.toDate())` or `new Date(t.date)` and `t` is returned.